# Why DataTable.Rows.ImportRow doesn't work when passing new created DataRow?

Tags: c#, datatable, datarow

I need to add `newRow` to `MyHandler` and it should add that row to the table that was built internally from the "scheme" that was passed to the MyHandler.
The problem is when I use `dt.ImportRow(row);` it doesn't add any row.
If I add `newRow` to `t` table and then do `handler.Add(t.row[t.Rows.Count - 1]);` so it works, but I don't want to add to `t` table. The `t` is just so I could create new row.

Why `dt.ImportRow(row);` doesn't work? How to fix it?

```
{
   var t = new DataTable();
   t.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Col1", typeof(string)));
   t.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Col2", typeof(byte)));
   t.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Col3", typeof(byte)));
   t.Rows.Add("a", 1, 1);
   t.Rows.Add("b", 2, 2);

   // MyHandler build internal table from the scheme
   var handler = new MyHandler(t.Clone());

   var newRow = t.NewRow();
   row["Col1"] = "c";
   row["Col2"] = 3;
   row["Col3"] = 3;

   handler.Add(row);
}

public class MyHandler
{
    DataTable dt;
    public class MyHandler(DataTable scheme)
    {
        dt = scheme;
    }
    public void Add(DataRow row)
    {
       dt.ImportRow(row);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should only use `ImportRow` to add rows from another DataTable.  Per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.newrow.aspx), rows created with `DataTable.NewRow` should be added with `DataTable.Rows.Add`.

Comment: so the only way is to add the `newRow` to `t` table and than do `handler.Add(t.row[t.Rows.Count - 1]);`?